# Website is not showing on GitHub Pages after deployment

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

This is my first time deploying onto GH Pages and it seemed like everything was right.  It states "Your site is published at [https://shayanvalaie.github.io/portfolio/"](https://shayanvalaie.github.io/portfolio/%22) but after going to the address it gives me a getting started with react page.

After doing some research I found that it might be due to the fact that it is taking my master branch and the solution was to change to the gh-pages branch but after checking it seems I don't have a gh-pages branch.

This is my package.json

````
  "homepage": "https://shayanvalaie.github.io/portfolio/",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.17.5",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.5.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-typed": "^1.2.0",
    "tsparticles": "^1.36.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}```
````

Comment: Have you *pushed* your changes?

Comment: @Martheen Yes I have

Comment: Nope https://github.com/shayanvalaie/portfolio/branches

Comment: @Martheen https://github.com/shayanvalaie/portfolio it shows all the files have been pushed here.  Also when I just tried pushing right now I got the message "On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'." Am I missing a step?

Comment: Did you clone the original repo then work on gh-pages branch? If so, you need to push that branch. Otherwise test first by running on your local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  I was following a botched tutorial and it missed the step where I need to run "npm run deploy".